# Problema: validación de formularios dentro de collapse bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

```js
$("#formCliente").validate({
  rules: {
    nombreEmpresa: {
      required: true
    },
    tipoIndustria: {
      required: true
    },
    textUbicacion: {
      required: true
    }
  },
  messages: {
    nombreEmpresa: "Debe completar todos los campos obligatorios!",
    tipoIndustria: "Debe completar todos los campos obligatorios!",
    textUbicacion: "Debe completar todos los campos obligatorios!"
  },
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    $('#errorCliente').empty();
    $('#errorCliente').html(error);

    element.next("div").addClass("errorDropDown");
  }
});


////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$("#idGuardarRequerimiento").click(function(e) {
  if (isValidForm("#formCliente", "#errorCliente", e)) {
    alert("Form invalido");
  }
});

function isValidForm(idForm, idError, event) {
  if (!$(idForm).valid()) {
    if (!$(idError).is(':visible')) {
      $(idError).show();
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    } else {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    $(idError).hide();
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="abmRequerimiento" class="collapse">
  <br>
  <h3 class="x_title_search"><i class="fa fa-suitcase" aria-hidden="true"></i> Agregar Nuevo Requerimiento</h3>
  <p class="text-info">Todos los campos con <b>*</b> son obligatorios.</p>
  <br>
  <!-- FORMULARIO /// ACCORDION -->
  <div class="col-xs-11">
    @*
    <div style="width:100%;text-align:center;">
      <span id="errorLabel"></span>
    </div>*@
    <!-- start accordion -->
    <div class="accordion" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
      <!-- Cliente y Contacto -->
      <div class="panel" id="idPanelOne">
        <a class="panel-heading collapse" role="tab" id="headingOne" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          <h4 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-volume-control-phone text-purple" aria-hidden="true"></i> Cliente y Contacto</h4>
        </a>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
          <div class="panel-body" style="margin-left:5px">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <h4>Cliente</h4>
              <br>
              <form id="formCliente" data-parsley-validate>
                <div style="width:100%;text-align:center;">
                  <span id="errorCliente"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="nombreEmpresa">Cliente <i class="fa fa-asterisk"></i></label>
                    <input type="text" id="nombreEmpresa" class="form-control" name="nombreEmpresa" placeholder="Ingresa el nombre de la empresa solicitante." />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="tipoIndustria">Industria <i class="fa fa-asterisk"></i></label>
                    <input type="text" id="tipoIndustria" class="form-control" name="tipoIndustria" placeholder="Ingresa la Industria." />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12" id="newContenedorUbicacion">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="textUbicacion">Ubicación <i class="fa fa-asterisk"></i></label>
                    <input type="text" id="textUbicacion" class="form-control" name="textUbicacion" @*onpaste="newSetearValidacionTimeout();" onkeydown="newSetearValidacionTimeout();" onblur="newValidarDireccionAsignacion();" *@ placeholder="Ingresa la Ubicación." />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
              <br>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Como andan?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Tengo un html con varios collapse. Dentro de éstos, tengo formularios los cuales hago las validaciones necesarias para los campos.

Al final de los collapse, tengo un botón que valida todos los collapse con sus respectivos formularios emitiendo un alert si es valido o no.

Cuando abro un collapse y hago click en el boton funciona todo bien (emite el mensaje de forms inválidos).

**El problema que tengo es que cuando no abro ningún collapse (no completo ningún campo) al hacer click en el botón, emite el mensaje que todos los formularios son válidos y debería decirme que son inválidos, ya que no complete ningún campo.**

Agradezco por la ayuda.

Comment: coloca el codigo

Comment: por favor coloca tu còdigo si quieres que el còdigo de la respuesta se parezca al tuyo

Comment: Ok. Agregado, es un fragmento

Comment: Resuelto!!! En la función validate agregué la propiedad ignore: false, antes de definir las reglas